# Defining multiple relations in Yii php

Tags: php, yii, relationship, foreign-key-relationship, relation

i'm new to Yii.

I have 3 tables.

**Entry, Study** and **Program**

Relation is: A Study has many Entries and a Study belongs to a single Program.

I wish to define a model for Entry to display a databrowser (CGridView) containing all entries, and displaying the Program that entry belongs to.

- Entry has **study_id** -> referring to Study,
- Study has **program_id** -> referring to a Program,
- Program has attribute **name**.

I wish to display the program name where the Entry belongs to.
I just know how to define a single relation Entry, but i'm totally clueless with my present problem. What should be my relation for this? and what attribute/s?

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
    ...
    'study' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Study', 'study_id'),
    );

}
```

And also, if i have this relation, how will i define my sort then for the dataprovider?

```
'sort'=>array(
    'attributes'=>array(
        '*'
    )
)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define these two relations in your model class.

```
'study' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Entry','study_id'),
'program'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Program',array('program_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'study'),
```

Now in your view file, you write `var_dump($data->program)` It will show list of programs of your specific entry.

You can also get help from my this link.

[How to get data from Relations with joins in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213045/how-to-get-data-from-relations-with-joins-in-yii)

Hope it will help you.

Thanks